# How to do NMOS modeling analysis in Spice

Tags: ltspice, nmos

Here is my circuit in Spice:

[image]

I want to do a simple analysis of the NMOS like this:

[image]

What kind of command should I use?

Comment: The red line is the "load line". When Id=0, Vd=10V. When Vd=0, Id=10/10k=1mA. This line help founding the Quiet Point if one knows bias voltage.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you need? Do you need the I/V curves? If yes, you are already set. Do you need to see a dynamic behaviour? Other calculations? ...?

Answer (score 1):

This would produce the Id curves. Not sure about the red line though... Maybe just add the equation in the plot window as a trace.

[image]

Edit: realized this was not what you wanted. You wanted a plot against varying Vd. So here it is:

[image]

If you add a measurement of R2 of the right hand NMOS and edit (rightclick on trace name) the trace function to "1m+I(R2)" you should get a load line.

Comment: Best use `.DC` for this because it calculates the operating point, only. whereas `.TRAN` may introduce variations due to the time response. So OP already has the setup, but the request is very vague.